# How to split a vector into n vectors and print them in one table in R?

Tags: r

I want to split a vector, for example:

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

let n=2
   m=c(4,6)
y<-split(x,rep(1:n,m))
```

I need to print y as a table like:

```
y1 y2
1  5
2  6
3  7
4  8
  9
  10
```

How to print y with different rows? Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a dataframe/matrix of unequal length in R, you can append `NA`'s to vector with shorter length.

```
sapply(y, `[`, seq_len(max(lengths(y))))

#      1  2
#[1,]  1  5
#[2,]  2  6
#[3,]  3  7
#[4,]  4  8
#[5,] NA  9
#[6,] NA 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of splitting the data in the first place, you can consider a `matrix` and use matrix indexing to insert the values at the relevant positions. It's very fast.

```
M <- matrix(NA, ncol = 2, nrow = max(m))
M[cbind(sequence(m), rep(seq_along(m), m))] <- x
M
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    5
# [2,]    2    6
# [3,]    3    7
# [4,]    4    8
# [5,]   NA    9
# [6,]   NA   10
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `stri_list2matrix` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
y1 <- stri_list2matrix(y)
```